# How to sort output lines in Fortran

Tags: sorting, fortran, output, line

I am using the following Fortran code:

```
       OPEN(3,FILE='input_2.data')

       I = 0
       J = 0

        DO I=1,3

        READ(3,*) NIA,NIB,NIC,RA,RB,RC,RD

        DO J=1,3
        RD = RD + 0.1

        WRITE(*,100) NIA,NIB,NIC,RA,RB,RC,RD
  100   FORMAT (I3,1X,I1,1X,I2,1X,F10.6,1X,F10.6,1X,F10.6,1X,F10.6)

        END DO
        END DO
```

to read the following input and increase 0.1 the values of the last column

```
 125 1 8 0.378000 -3.358451 -0.205840 10.482472

 126 1 9 0.112000 -3.542726 -0.308731 11.559977

 127 1 10 -0.400000 -4.275883 -0.114349 9.690803
```

and then output like this

```
 125 1  8   0.378000  -3.358451  -0.205840  10.582473

 126 1  9   0.112000  -3.542726  -0.308731  11.659977

 127 1 10  -0.400000  -4.275883  -0.114349   9.790803

 125 1  8   0.378000  -3.358451  -0.205840  10.682473

 126 1  9   0.112000  -3.542726  -0.308731  11.759977

 127 1 10  -0.400000  -4.275883  -0.114349   9.890803

 125 1  8   0.378000  -3.358451  -0.205840  10.782474

 126 1  9   0.112000  -3.542726  -0.308731  11.859978

 127 1 10  -0.400000  -4.275883  -0.114349   9.990804
```

However, my Fortran output looks like this:

```
 125 1  8   0.378000  -3.358451  -0.205840  10.582473

 125 1  8   0.378000  -3.358451  -0.205840  10.682473

 125 1  8   0.378000  -3.358451  -0.205840  10.782474

 126 1  9   0.112000  -3.542726  -0.308731  11.659977

 126 1  9   0.112000  -3.542726  -0.308731  11.759977

 126 1  9   0.112000  -3.542726  -0.308731  11.859978

 127 1 10  -0.400000  -4.275883  -0.114349   9.790803

 127 1 10  -0.400000  -4.275883  -0.114349   9.890803

 127 1 10  -0.400000  -4.275883  -0.114349   9.990804
```

Is there a workaround by which I could sort the output lines in Fortran?

I would deeply appreciate any suggestion!

Comment: Please use the formatting features available in the question editor to format any code snippets or text tables.. I did it for you here. Please note that Fortran has been spelled Fortran for more than 3 decades. Also note that using indentation can make the code much more readable. That is true also in fixed-form Fortran. You do not have to start your line at column 7, it can be any column after 7.

Comment: You can always sort any data. You *could* store the output strings in some array and sort that array. But in your case I would simply read the input file 3 times (e.g. by using `rewind`).

Answer (score 0):

As  commented, you can achieve your order by changing the loop to go through the file three times and increase `RD` each time

```
       OPEN(3,FILE='input_2.data')
      
       RD_INC = 0

       DO I=1,3

         RD_INC = RD_INC + 0.1

         DO J=1,3

           READ(3,*) NIA,NIB,NIC,RA,RB,RC,RD

           WRITE(*,100) NIA,NIB,NIC,RA,RB,RC,RD+RD_INC
  100      FORMAT (I3,1X,I1,1X,I2,1X,F10.6,1X,F10.6,1X,F10.6,1X,F10.6)

         END DO
        
         REWIND(3)
        
       END DO
        
       END
```

On the other hand, `I` and `J` do not have to be defined before the loop. All variables should be declared and `IMPLICIT NONE` should be used.